# Images disappear from entry

Tags: matrix, file-field

I've just been contacted by a client who is finding that images are missing from a file field when an already published entry is reopened. Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Edit: The file field is within Matrix 2.2.4, EE is v2.4. Original installation was around two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Matrix 2.5.10 fixed the problem